# dup2 does not redirect socket on windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets, popen, dup2

I try to redirect the output of a popen write fd to a socket instead of stdout.

I write a small yet unfinished webserver in C with PHP support. For this I open `php-cgi` with `popen` in write mode (for post request for example).
To send the output to the client socket I want to use `dup2`, but this seems not to work.
Everytime the PHP code output is send to stdout.

(If I use `popen` in read mode, the content of the PHP code is displayed correctly to the HTTP client, but by this I can't write args to PHP-CGI.)

Since I'm on Windows, I already tried the windows commands `_dup2` with `_filno(stdout)`, without any success.
Also unfortunatley `fork()` and `pipe()` is not an option because of Windows (even pipe exists, but fork does not AFAIK).

```
... snip: setting up env, creating php neccessary cgi args ...

writeall(socket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Web Server in C\r\nConnection:: close\r\n");

dup2(socket, STDOUT_FILENO);

FILE *phpproc = popen("php-cgi", "w");
if(strcmp(reqtype, "POST") == 0) {
    fputs(args, phpproc);
}
pclose(phpproc);

... snip: cleaning up sockets close connections etc
```

As mentioned everything is send to stdout instead to the socket, the header before dup2 is also send, but the HTTP client gets an empty response, because of the wrong output destination.

Comment: Correct. Sockets are not first-class citizens in Windows. A socket handle is not an `fd` in the C library sense, and can't be used in `close(), dup()`, dup2(), ...`.

Comment: Any suggestions how to get this tonwork without forking?